# Change route to subdomain in Laravel

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, subdomain, cloudflare

I have a url in my Laravel App: https://domain.com/admin , now i want to move it to `https://admin.domain.com` .I use Cloudflare as nameserver , nginx. When i access `https://admin.domain.com` it show red https warning and when i access `http://admin.domain.com` it show nginx test page. How could i do that?
I created subdomain 'admin' in cloudflare (Cname)
Nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name www.domain.tv;
        rewrite ^(.*) https://domain.tv$1 permanent;
        }
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.domain.tv;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {    
    listen 443 ssl http2; # Use this config for Nginx from 1.9.5 version
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl http2; # Use this config for Nginx before 1.9.5 version
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.tv/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.tv/domain.tv.key; 
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!CAMELLIA:!DES-CBC3-SHA;
    #ssl_stapling on;
    #resolver 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
    #resolver_timeout 10s;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.tv/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_buffer_size 1400;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
        # error_log /home/domain.tv/logs/error.log;
        root /home/domain.tv/public_html/MovieWebApp/public;    
    include /etc/nginx/conf/ddos2.conf;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name *.domain.tv;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a A Record for every single subdomain, you have to use a (*) redirect with cloudflare and nginx to achieve this. I think cloudflare does not offer asterix redirects for free though.

Comment: How to create a (*) redirect on nginx , i already have a A record with name  is (*)

Comment: Just set the server_name to *.yourdomain.io, it will then work for all subdomains if you do not override it with another server, you're getting the  "red https warning" because your https cert is most likely just signed for a single subdomain

Comment: Show me what the nginx server looks like

Comment: Weird, this worked for me before I started using cloudflare and couldnt use asterix redirects anymore